# django dynamic forms based on query result in one template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a requirement which a bit new on this django framework. i have been searching alot but couldnt find.

```
<h2> Main Table </h2>

ID = Primary Key
Position= CharField

<h2> Child Table </h2>

position=foreignkey(main table)
employee=CharField
attendance=CharField
```

Scenario

I have a listview with following data as an example in the template.

```
<Table> 
<th> ID </th>
<th> Position</th>
<th> Update </th>
<td>1</td>
<td>Manager</td>
<td><a href="#">Click </a> </td>
<tr></tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Staff</td>
<td><a href="#">Click </a> </td>
</table>
```

#### I need to create dynamic forms in the update template based on child table rows in a data grid to update attendance

Comment: Please post your actual code (only the relevant parts) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: i couldnt do it, thats why no code is attached

Comment: You could not write any code? Then maybe start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/